# Ошибка Gulp при компиляции Sass

Tags: javascript, gulp, sass, gulp-sass, gulp-watch

Столкнулся с ошибкой при использовании `gulp` для сборки проекта. Текст самой ошибки:

```
gulp-notify: [Error running Gulp] app\sass\main.sass
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: media.
   Parent style sheet: G:/MeraxeS/decstop/start-template/app/sass/main.sass
    on line 395 of app/sass/main.sass
>> @import "media";
  ^
```

Погуглив данный вопрос, к сожалению, не нашел понятного мне решения. Ошибка появляется при изменении только импортируемых файлов. Как в данном случае `media.sass`. При редактировании основного `main.sass` ошибка не возникает. 
Если правильно понял, проблема скорее всего в том, что таск watch пытается получить доступ к файлу раньше, чем тот успевает сохраниться на диске.

Пишут что есть какой-то хак с использованием `setTimeOut` или можно поработать с опциями плагина `gulp-watch`, но как применить это в моем случае не соображу, в документации ничего похожего не нашел, к своему стыду плохо разбираюсь в `js`.

Опытные кодеры, подскажите, что нужно поправить в коде моего `gulpfile.js`, чтобы компиляция проходила без ошибки?!

Код представлен ниже. Заранее благодарю за помощь.

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/sass/**/*.sass')
  .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'expand'}).on("error", notify.onError()))
  .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min', prefix : ''}))
  .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions']))
  .pipe(cleanCSS())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
  .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['sass', 'js', 'browser-sync'], function() {
  gulp.watch('app/sass/**/*.sass', ['sass']);
  gulp.watch(['libs/**/*.js', 'app/js/common.js'], ['js']);
  gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Все оказалось намного проще, проблема возникает в редакторе sublime text только c HDD. SSD файл пишется быстрее, поэтому проблемы нет на компьютерах с SDD.

Решается просто настройкой atomic save в sublime. По умолчанию в настройках стоит значение "atomic_save": false, меняешь на true и вопрос решается раз и навсегда без каких-либо костылей с setTimeout или любой другой задержкой обновления страницы.

Спасибо Алексею Циня, за ценный совет в решении данной проблемы.